# Force android Gmail sync in background

Tags: android, synchronization, gmail, tasker

The Gmail app on my phone is not syncing email anymore unless it is opened in foreground.
(This is a known issue on several OnePlus devices after the Android 11 upgrade).
Is there any activity or intent that can be used to force the sync in the background?

At this moment I'm giving a shot to some Macrodroid / Tasker scripts but it works only if the app is opened in foreground.
I'm looking for something that can be triggered in background.

Comment: Try adding a gmail widget to your home screen so it's always running.